# Test relations in Laravel 4 with FactoryMuff

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, many-to-many

I am new to TDD, so excuse me if this is a noob question.

I have Users and Projects, related in 2 different ways:

1. A Project Belongs to a User
2. Many Users can be authorized to many Projects.

I am following this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models/?search_index=16 , so I am using FactoryMuff.

This is my Project class:

```
 <?php
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
class Project extends Ardent
{
    /**
     * Ardent validation rules
     */
    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',              // Project Title
        'user_id' => 'required|numeric',  // User owner id
    );

    /**
     * Array used by FactoryMuff to create Test objects
     */
    public static $factory = array(
        'name' => 'string',
        'user_id' => 'factory|User', // Will be the id of an existent User.
    );

    /**
     * Belongs to user
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'User', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Many Users can be authorized
     */
    public function authorized()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'User', 'project_user', 'project_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

And this is my User class:

```
 <?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

class User extends ConfideUser {

    /**
     * Ardent validation rules
     */
    public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|min:4|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'              => 'required|between:4,16|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|between:4,16',
    );

    /**
     * Array used by FactoryMuff to create Test objects
     */
    public static $factory = array(
        'username' => 'string',
        'email' => 'email',
        'password' => '12345',
        'password_confirmation' => '12345',
    );

    (more code)

    /**
     * Many Users can be authorized on many Projects
     */
    public function authorized()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'Project', 'project_user', 'user_id', 'project_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Users can have many Projects
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( 'Project');
    }

}
```

And this is my ProjectTest:

```
 <?php
use Zizaco\FactoryMuff\Facade\FactoryMuff;
use Way\Tests\Factory;
class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{
    use Way\Tests\ModelHelpers;
    /**
     * Test relationship with User
     */
    public function testRelationshipWithUser()
    {
      // Instantiate new Project
      $project = FactoryMuff::create('Project');

      $this->assertEquals($project->user_id, $project->owner->id);
  }

    /**
     * Test relationship with Authorized Users
     */
    public function testRelationshipWithAuthorizedUsers()
    {
      // Instantiate new Project
      $project = FactoryMuff::create('Project');
      $project->save();
      $project->authorized()->attach($project->user_id);

      $this->assertEquals($project->user_id, $project->authorized->first()->id);
  }

}
```

If I run the tests individually (commenting the other) both pass. However, if I run both, I get this error:

```
Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table users has no column named password_confirmation
```

Why is it complaining about that column in the second test and not in the first? :S

Comment: This is not many to many! Many to many requires a pivot table, e.g. project_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;` on your `User` model.

Ardent (which Confide extends from) will automatically purge the `_confirmation` fields, but by default it is set to false.

Comment: Now I get this: ) ProjectModelTest::testRelationshipWithAuthorizedUsers
Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 users.confirmation_code may not be NULL (SQL: insert into "users" ("username", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array (
  0 => 'Course',
  1 => 'grin@emailprovider.com',
  2 => '$2y$08$6UVyR53rqyqpq613tEqsLOvJYD6QfNfkELbnhPS0pjt4H8KAMxt1a',
  3 => '2013-12-04 20:39:22',
  4 => '2013-12-04 20:39:22',
))

Comment: You might have to provide a `confirmation_code` in your factory. For some reason the `beforeSave` method mustn't be getting fired.